# Unity launcher icons have no background colors (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS)

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

How can I reset unity application icons. I find it difficult to identify which is which sometimes.

[image: unity launcher icons no colours]

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you've accidentally changed your default theme to **High Contrast Theme and icons**

you need to install unity tweak tool and change the theme back to **Adwaita (Default)**

to install unity tweak tool, paste this in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

then open unity tweak tool from the dash and change the theme back to default